# seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am uploading an image to memory then I want to save it to an imageField().

I use django-storages that uploads files from image/fileField() to AWS S3.

I download the image to the memory:

```
        r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
        image_in_memory = InMemoryUploadedFile(image, None, "foo.png",  'image/png', image.size, None)
        image_in_memory_file = image_in_memory.file
```

Some verifications:

```
print(type(image_in_memory))

---
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
```

When I save this:

```
my_object.cover.save(name="foo.png", content=image_in_memory)
```

Django generates this error:

```
web_1      |     link.cover.save(name="foo.png", content=image_in_memory)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 87, in save
web_1      |     self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 52, in save
web_1      |     return self._save(name, content)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 491, in _save
web_1      |     self._save_content(obj, content, parameters=parameters)
web_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 505, in _save_content
web_1      |     content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
web_1      | TypeError: seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should use `content=image_in_memory_file`?

Comment: I also tried it and got the same error: `seek() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given `

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping the file in a Pillow Image class for some reason. The Image `seek` method is meant for image sequences and, as the error explains, takes two positional arguments.

Don't wrap it as an Image:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
image = BytesIO(r.content)
image_in_memory = InMemoryUploadedFile(image, None, "foo.png",  'image/png', len(r.content), None)
```

Also note there's a simpler class, SimpleUploadedFile, which just takes the name and content and which is probably what you need here:

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
image_in_memory = SimpleUploadedFile("foo.png", r.content, 'image/png')
```

Comment: Have the same issue. I need to wrap the image in order to resize it. How to save resized image?